# Парсинг таблицы на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Хочу спарсить на питоне табличку с сайта.

Вопрос как лучше разобрать столбцы таблицы?

Ниже html код где описана таблица и скриншот сайта.

Мой код еще ниже:

```html
<div class="" id="products">
<section class="row section list-articles-content box-shadow bg-white">
<div class="section-title col-12" id="tab-Jogurt do 0.5l">
<h4 class="text-left">Jogurt do 0.5l</h4>
</div>
<div class="border-gray d-flex flex-nowrap flex-row article-row col-6 col-md-12 p-0 " data-product-id="1009568" data-zoom-image="/img/articles/jogurt-meggle-chia-crna-ribizla-i-borovnica-330g-1009568-medium.jpg">
<div class="article-hover article-image border-gray-right flex-full-height-center p-1">
<a href="/artikal/1009568/jogurt-meggle-chia-crna-ribizla-i-borovnica-330g">
<img alt="Jogurt MEGGLE chia crna ribizla i borovnica 330g" src="/img/articles/jogurt-meggle-chia-crna-ribizla-i-borovnica-330g-1009568-medium.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="article-hover article-name flex-full-height-center border-gray-right p-1">
<a href="/artikal/1009568/jogurt-meggle-chia-crna-ribizla-i-borovnica-330g">Jogurt MEGGLE chia crna ribizla i borovnica 330g</a>
</div>
<div class="article-qty flex-full-height-center border-gray-right text-center">330 g</div>
<div class="article-add-list flex-full-height-center border-gray-right text-center">
<!--
                    <div class="cart-img"></div>
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i>
                    <div class="thingie"><span>0</span></div>
                -->
<a data-target="#login" data-toggle="modal" href="#">
<i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i>
</a>
</div>
<div class="article-price flex-full-height-center border-gray-right text-center" data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
<div class="shop align-self-center p-0 d-md-none" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cene su poslednji put ažurirane 08.10.2018. godine.">
<img alt="Idea" src="/bundles/cenoteka/images/shops/100Idea.png"/>
</div>
<div class="price p-0">
                    104,99
                </div>
</div>
<div class="article-price flex-full-height-center border-gray-right text-center" data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
<div class="shop align-self-center p-0 d-md-none" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cene su poslednji put ažurirane 15.10.2018. godine. Cene se isključuvo odnose na format Maxi na teritoriji grada Beograda (ne i Shop&amp;Go)">
<img alt="Maxi" src="/bundles/cenoteka/images/shops/200Maxi.png"/>
</div>
<div class="price p-0">
                    99,99
                </div>
</div>
<div class="article-price flex-full-height-center border-gray-right text-center" data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
<div class="shop align-self-center p-0 d-md-none" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cene su poslednji put ažurirane 15.10.2018. godine.">
<img alt="Univerexport" src="/bundles/cenoteka/images/shops/250Univer.png"/>
</div>
<div class="price p-0">
                    106,99
                </div>
</div>
<div class="article-price flex-full-height-center border-gray-right text-center" data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
<div class="shop align-self-center p-0 d-md-none" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cene su poslednji put ažurirane 12.10.2018. godine. Cene se odnose na objekat Tempo Kvantaš">
<img alt="Tempo" src="/bundles/cenoteka/images/shops/300Tempo.png"/>
</div>
<div class="price lowest p-0">
                    94,99
                </div>
</div>
<div class="article-price flex-full-height-center border-gray-right text-center" data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
<div class="shop align-self-center p-0 d-md-none" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cene su poslednji put ažurirane 05.10.2018. godine. Cene se odnose na objekat na adresi Autoput 18 (kod Zmaj pumpe).">
<img alt="DIS" src="/bundles/cenoteka/images/shops/400DIS.png"/>
</div>
<div class="price p-0">
                    100,99
                </div>
</div>
<div class="article-price flex-full-height-center border-gray-right text-center" data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
<div class="shop align-self-center p-0 d-md-none" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cene su poslednji put ažurirane 11.10.2018. godine. Cene se odnose na objekat Roda Cash&amp;Carry na adresi Autoput 18 (Beograd, kod Zmaj pumpe)">
<img alt="Roda" src="/bundles/cenoteka/images/shops/500Roda.png"/>
</div>
<div class="price p-0">
                    99,99
                </div>
</div>
<div class="article-price flex-full-height-center border-gray-right text-center no-price">
<div class="shop align-self-center p-0 d-md-none" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cene su poslednji put ažurirane 15.10.2018. godine.">
<img alt="Lidl" src="/bundles/cenoteka/images/shops/800Lidl.png"/>
</div>`введите сюда код`
<div class="price">
                    - 
                </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, fake_useragent
from time import sleep

ua = fake_useragent.UserAgent() 
user = ua.random
header = {'User-Agent':str(user)}

url  = 'https://cenoteka.rs/proizvodi/mlecni-proizvodi/jogurt?page=3'
response = requests.get(url,headers = header) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
i = soup.find('div', id = 'products')
print(i)
```

Подскажите, как распарсить таблицу?

Comment: А что вытаскивать хотите? Название и цены?

Comment: Нужно название категории, название продукта и цены.

Comment: А категории это эти Йогурты до 0.5, до 1 и т.п.?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно.

Answer (score 4):

Код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://cenoteka.rs/proizvodi/mlecni-proizvodi/jogurt?page=3'
rs = requests.get(url)
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')

for category in root.select('#products > .row.section'):
    category_title = category.select_one('.section-title').get_text(strip=True)
    print(category_title)

    for product in category.select('[data-product-id]'):
        try:
            title = product.select_one('.article-name').get_text(strip=True)
            price_list = [price.get_text(strip=True) for price in product.select('.article-price')]
            print('    {}: {}'.format(title, price_list))

        except:
            pass

    print()
```

Консоль:

```
Jogurt do 0.5l
    Jogurt MEGGLE chia crna ribizla i borovnica 330g: ['104,99', '99,99', '106,99', '94,99', '100,99', '99,99', '-']
    Jogurt MEGGLE chia jabuka banana spanać 330g: ['104,99', '99,99', '104,99', '94,99', '100,99', '99,99', '-']
    Jogurt MEGGLE chia natur 330g: ['99,99', '94,99', '101,99', '89,99', '97,99', '94,99', '-']

Jogurt do 1l
    Jogurt AB 1kg: ['-', '-', '-', '113,99', '-', '-', '-']
    Jogurt BALANS+ protein 750g Imlek: ['-', '-', '-', '94,99', '-', '94,99', '-']
    Jogurt DUKAT 3,2%mm 1kg: ['84,99', '88,99', '84,99', '104,99', '106,99', '104,99', '104,99']
    Jogurt DUKAT light 1,5%mm 1kg: ['-', '107,99', '-', '87,99', '112,99', '-', '-']
    Jogurt DUKAT SenSia 1kg: ['-', '94,99', '89,99', '89,99', '-', '111,99', '-']
    Jogurt IMLEK 2,8% gusti 1kg: ['99,99', '118,99', '-', '113,99', '107,99', '96,99', '-']
    Jogurt IMLEK Balans+ 1kg: ['115,99', '109,99', '-', '109,99', '99,99', '99,99', '-']
    Jogurt IMLEK Bello 750g: ['129,99', '-', '131,99', '125,99', '-', '126,99', '-']
    Jogurt IMLEK Moja kravica 2,8% 1kg DC: ['112,99', '94,99', '121,99', '107,99', '107,99', '-', '-']
    Jogurt IMLEK Moja kravica 2,8% 1kg TT: ['112,99', '-', '121,99', '107,99', '-', '94,99', '-']
    Jogurt MEGGLE 0,5%mm 1kg: ['107,99', '79,99', '-', '74,99', '-', '-', '-']
    Jogurt MEGGLE 2,8%mm 1kg: ['109,99', '105,99', '-', '101,99', '89,99', '107,99', '-']
    Jogurt MLEKARA SUBOTICA Zdravo 2,8%mm 1kg: ['-', '109,99', '111,99', '104,99', '-', '-', '-']
    Jogurt 2,8%mm 1kg (robna marka): ['99,99', '87,99', '-', '87,99', '-', '-', '-']
    Jogurt 2,8%mm K Plus 1Kg: ['99,99', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
    Jogurt 2,8%mm Premia 1Kg: ['-', '87,99', '-', '87,99', '-', '-', '-']

Jogurt do 2l
    Jogurt AB 1,45kg: ['-', '-', '169,99', '154,99', '-', '164,99', '-']
```

---

**PS.** интересно, что на той странице есть сломанные теги и парсер `html.parser` не обнаруживал у `#products` детей, а вот `lxml` смог

Comment: Спасибо! Это очень круто!

Comment: Можно еще добавить имена столбцов:Idea, Maxi,...Lidl. Но это я думаю сам смогу)) и в CSV файл все выгружу.

Comment: @ИванПетров, тогда примите ответ :)

Comment: gil9red, а как вытащить данные из <div class="border-gray d-flex flex-nowrap flex-row article-row col-6 col-md-12 p-0 " data-product-id="1006155" data-zoom-image="/img/articles/ananas-iska-kocka-560g-1006155-medium.jpg"> мне нужен ID продукта 1006155 ?

Comment: На этом сайте принято принимать ответы, так вы благодарите автора ответа, `print(product['data-product-id'])`